# How to set a pragma to constrain Ada's functionality to Pascal

Tags: ada

I intend to use Ada for some programs. I remember reading somewhere that with pragmas you can set compiler instructions to optimize your program. More specifically, I remember reading that if you need only a limited subset of Ada functionality (basically corresponding to Pascal, but with Ada's strong typing), you can use pragmas to specify a sort of 'Pascal-like mode' (I use this term for lack of a better expression). My aim is disabling those runtime checks that I don't need (since I only need basic functionality), thus reducing the size of the executable and enhancing the performance.
My question is: how do I set such a pragma? What parameters/options should I specify?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This perhaps comes from a misunderstanding.

Ada is not a superset of Pascal. It is a fair bit more accurate to view them as sibling languages of the parent language [Algol 60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL). Pascal was orginally developed by Niklaus Wirth to be a **simplified** version of Algol 60. The Algol folks instead went the other way with what became Algol 68.

Ada was instead a new language designed from scratch that borrowed from Algol 60's syntax (in much the way that Java borrows from C's syntax). It is however much more complex (some would use the word "functional") than even Algol 68.

So asking for a "Pascal flag" in your Ada compiler is much like asking for a "C++ flag" in your Java compiler.

If you are just looking for a free Pascal compiler, you might instead look at using [Free Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Pascal) or [GNU Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Pascal).

If you are just looking to decrease the overhead of unused runtime facilities, you should look into [Annex H](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-H-4.html), which lets you to use [`pragma Restrictions()`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-12.html) to selectively disallow access to parts of the Ada runtime. That allows you to get rid of things like floating-point, dynamic allocation, dynamic dispatch, tasking, exceptions/runtime constraint checks, etc.

Comment: But note that a compiler isn't *required* to take advantage of the restrictions to improve efficiency ([ARM 13.12(17)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-12.html#p17)).

Comment: @SimonWright - Not only that, as near as I can tell it isn't really required to support or even enforce the restrictions at all. If you want the actual effect of not having that part of the runtime (rather than just documenting that you don't intend to use it) you should really be checking your compiler docs to see what it actually does for Annex H stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but this is a Bad Idea. If you want to avoid any possible overhead from tasking constructs, then don't use tasking! People often want to suppress constraint checking (which you can do in GNAT by compiling with `-p`) but - in my experience - you rarely get more than a small improvement.

Ada now has [pragma Restrictions](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-12.html), which prevents you using certain features; you can see GNAT's [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Partition_002dWide-Restrictions.html#Partition_002dWide-Restrictions). The aims are to support production of high-integrity software, portable software, or efficient tasking runtimes.

Answer (score -1):

That {'Pascal-like mode'} sounds like a implementation-specific pragma, unless I'm misunderstanding you.
Though there are the 'optimize`[time or space] and`restriction` pragmas that might impact your final size.